# Getting the screen brightness value in iOS 5

Tags: ios5, screen-brightness, uiscreen

I've started to use the new iOS 5 brightness setter in UIScreen. Is there a getter property I can use to know what the display brightness is set to on launch?

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The same property. These are the methods I use to store the current brightness before changing it, then reset brightness to the previous value later:

```c
- (void)dimScreen {
    previousBrightness = [UIScreen mainScreen].brightness;
    [UIScreen mainScreen].brightness = 0;
}

- (void)restoreScreen {
    [UIScreen mainScreen].brightness = previousBrightness;
}
```

**Update:** It's useful to note that the brightness reported by `UIScreen` is only the brightness the user has set in Settings, and does not report the auto brightness adjusted value. If auto brightness is enabled, I am aware of no way to get the adjusted value.

As an example, if the user has the brightness slider at 100% in Settings but they are currently in a very dark room, then `UIScreen` will report a brightness of 1.0, but the true value might be closer to 0.5.

Comment: iOS does not save this value. After lock/unlock your device will end up with the brightness controlled by system settings.

Comment: @MikhaloIvanokov In my example code I'm treating "previousBrightness" as an ivar, so yes, it's your responsibility to retain this value.